# pydrive: ImportError: cannot import name 'CredentialsFileSymbolicLinkError'

Tags: python

I was testing out pydrive module for python. On running the script named quick.py:

```
from pydrive.drive import GoogleAuth

gauth = GoogleAuth()
gauth.LocalWebserverAuth()
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "quick.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pydrive.drive import GoogleAuth
  File "/home/fauzan/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pydrive/drive.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .files import GoogleDriveFile
  File "/home/fauzan/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pydrive/files.py", line 12, in <module>
    from .auth import LoadAuth
  File "/home/fauzan/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pydrive/auth.py", line 15, in <module>
    from oauth2client.file import CredentialsFileSymbolicLinkError
ImportError: cannot import name 'CredentialsFileSymbolicLinkError'
```

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: Read the Python tag. You are asking an off-topic question. Please read [On-Topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic), [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://superuser.com/help/dont-ask)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was a [bug](https://github.com/googledrive/PyDrive/issues/78) due to the upgraded oath2client 4.0.0. The bug has been squashed and the updated pydrive package is live on PyPi.

```
pip install pydrive --upgrade
```

will solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This problem arises in oauth2client==4.0.0 version.

After changing the version to 3.0.0, it works fine.

```
pip install oauth2client==3.0.0
```